# Do males wear under garments in Ihram?

Tags: men, hajj, umrah

I heard that, unlike females, male pilgrims wear only two sheets of cloth (Ihram).

Does this mean they are not allowed to wear undergarments to protect their modesty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

I will try be as short as possible.

> *An-Nawawi may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said: '**If a person in a
>   state of Ihraam (either for Hajj or 'Umrah) needs to cover his head,
>   or wear any limb-fitting clothes for a sound reason like heat, cold or
>   treatment, then it is permissible for him to cover but he is obliged
>   to slaughter a sheep.***"

So in short, men are not allowed to wear any extra cloth until or unless a sound reason, even with that reason he need to give FIDYAH which is slaughtering a sheep or fasting 3 days.

For details see this [Wearing underwear for necessity during Hajj or 'Umrah](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91249)

### Allah knows best